# Incomplete input data: is it better to abort processing or produce incomplete result?

Tags: usability

I'm having a hot debate with a colleague. We're working on an image processing software that accepts a set of images and produces a single result. The debate concerns the behavior when one or more of the source images cannot be loaded (e. g. corrupted). My colleague says the process should complete as if the problematic image was never added (with a warning message), and I say no result is better than a poor result: the process should be aborted and no result should be produced.

Thoughts?

Comment: Personally, I would stop processing. Why continue if your result could be bad/inaccurate? If possible, you could display a dialog telling them what failed to load, a warning of possible bad data, and options to either continue processing or to stop processing.

Comment: What is the output? The answer will be difference if it's a) stitching together an HDR image versus b) used for missile targeting software.

Comment: Midas is right, if the result has no value when one piece is missing than the process has failed and should be stopped. If the results are useful   individually than the process failed just partially and can continue.

Comment: Looking at the end-to-end process, does the user first select the images, then choose the processing options?

Comment: @Splatz: there are no options per se, this program is a one trick pony. You select the images and then commence processing.

Comment: So the user selects the images then triggers the processing. Do they select the images one at a time or in bulk? Do the images upload as they select them of does it upload the images when you trigger the Process button?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest Violet, you haven't provided enough info in your question for anyone to offer a definite answer to your particular problem. The way I see it, the answer will depend on the following variables:

- **What does processing the images produce?** - For example, if it produces an animated GIF image for use on internal SharePoint sites, that's less critical than processing a group of images to produce a facial composite for a murder investigation.
- **Who benefits from the final output?** - If the person benefiting from the final output is a teenager trying to make a funny animated GIF, well, a missing image won't matter and may in fact add to the result. If it's processing images to produce plates for a large printing company, well the workflow should stop with an error and guidance as to how to rectify it.

**My best guess answer**

On the information you've provided I would suggest that the number one thing from a user perspective is that they will want to know is if what they've done has been successful. That is, don't have the software process all images without at least some notification of the problem.

If it was me, I would **design it to notify users of what problem(s) have occurred and offer them the option of trying to upload the problem images again, abort, or continue.** This empowers the user and they can make an informed choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one general right answer for that debate. It depends on the nature of the result expected : is it modular ? or is it a general decision ? Let me give an example : in medical domain, these images may be images of patient  tissues, and the output required is a general decision : does the patient have certain type of tumor or not ? In such cases, you will not be willing to proceed with missing images, because present images may be clear (negative results) , while the missing ones contains tumor (positive results). But if the output of the program is modular, that is you are making some utility that do some stamping on images, or registering it in some kind of a database, then I think there will be no harm to carry on with the existing images, and retrying the missing images latter.

But in all cases : you have to clearly inform the user about the problem, give him an option to fix the problem (like : can not access shared image file on network, check network connection and retry) , and if there is some kind of a journal -logging system- in your application, log the event of "proceeding with missing images" for future auditing .

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the user 3 options;

- continue process, including corrupt data
- continue process, exclude corrupt data from the computation
- stop process, allowing user to replace corrupt data

As you've already noticed, people (e.g your and colleague) don't always agree on the best solution. In which case the best solution is to let the user decide. Not just on a person-by-person absolute rule, but also on a case-by-case basis.

Giving the users two options for processing lets them try both and then see which one they prefer. Those two options are for who think 'half a result is better than none'. The third option is for those who think 'no result is better than a bad result'.